# VBA copying a data label format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to copy the data label formatting from one series to another, but the code falls down at .font.size line

Run time error '438'
Object does not support this property or method

Despite Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Size=10

```
Sub copy_data_labels()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Cht_Sht As Chart
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim ref_series As Integer
Dim update_series As Integer

'text to reference data label series
OriV1 = "$21"
NewV1 = "$39"


For Each Cht_Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
    num_series = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection.Count
    ref_series = 0
    update_series = 0
    For i = 1 To num_series
        If InStr(1, Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, OriV1) > 0 Then ref_series = i
        If InStr(1, Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, NewV1) > 0 Then update_series = i
    Next i
    If ref_series > 0 And update_series > 0 Then
    'both series exist
        If Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).HasDataLabels Then
        'has data labels to copy
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).HasDataLabels = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).HasDataLabels
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.AutoText = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.AutoText
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.HorizontalAlignment = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.HorizontalAlignment
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.NumberFormat = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.NumberFormat
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Orientation = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Orientation
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Position = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Position
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Shadow = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Shadow
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.VerticalAlignment = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.VerticalAlignment
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Size  = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Size
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Bold = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Bold
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Name = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Name
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.FontStyle = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.FontStyle
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex
            Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Background = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Background
        End If
    End If
Next Cht_Sht

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I expected this code just to copy the font size over.

Comment: The code works fine here. Which version/build of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have a non-breaking space character (ascii 160), followed by a space character (ascii 32) in the following line between `.Font.Size` and `=`:

```
Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Size  = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Size
```

Answer (score 0):

Double space issue (after size) changed this;

```
Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Size  = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Size
```

to this;

```
Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(update_series).DataLabels.Font.Size = Cht_Sht.SeriesCollection(ref_series).DataLabels.Font.Size
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: If you had 2 spaces before the `=`, there was for sure something else wrong with that statement - else the VBA editor would have automatically corrected that line (try to add the space again).